# PHP MYSQL while loop till same value than break and sum, than do the same with next value

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, sum, case

I try to loop all my rows from MySQL, and I got it. The problem is I want to case them, I think its the correct expression. 
For example: MYSQL

```
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
| id |abholdatum|    fahrer   |    preis   |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
|  6 |14 11  15 |       martin|         22 |
|  7 |14 11  15 |       david |         25 |
|  8 |31 12  15 |       david |         22 |
|  10|29 12  15 |       martin|         23 |
|  12|30 12  15 |       david |         29 |
+----+----------+-------------+------------+
```

now I get this:

```
ID  Abholdatum          Fahrer  Preis
7   14 November 2015    david   25
8   31 Dezember 2015    david   22
12  30 Dezember 2015    david   29
6   14 November 2015    martin  22
10  29 Dezember 2015    martin  23
```

and I actually want this:

```
 ID Abholdatum          Fahrer  Preis
--------------------------------------
David   
    7   14 November 2015    david   25
    8   31 Dezember 2015    david   22
    12  30 Dezember 2015    david   29
--------------------------------------
Summ                                76
--------------------------------------
--------------------------------------
Martin 
     6  14 November 2015    martin  22
    10  29 Dezember 2015    martin  23
--------------------------------------
Summ                                45
--------------------------------------
```

and this is my simple php script:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($dbc, "select * from fahrten ORDER BY fahrer ASC");

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

        echo "<tr>" 
        . "<td>" . $row['id'] ."</td>" 
        . "<td>" . $row['abholdatum'] ."</td>" 
        . "<td>" .  $row['fahrer'] . "</td>"
        . "<td>" . $row['preis'] . "</td>"
        . "</tr>";
    }

    echo "</table>"
    . "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
$sql = mysqli_query($dbc, "select * from fahrten ORDER BY fahrer ASC");

    $fahrer = array();

     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
     if (!in_array($row['fahrer'], $fahrer))
             {
          $fahrer[] = $row['fahrer'];
          }
}
    foreach($fahrer as $value){
         echo "<tr>". $value ."</tr>";
         $sum=0;

    while ($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
       if($value = $row1['fahrer']){
    echo "<tr>" 
    . "<td>" . $row1['id'] ."</td>" 
    . "<td>" . $row1['abholdatum'] ."</td>" 
    . "<td>" .  $row1['fahrer'] . "</td>"
    . "<td>" . $row1['preis'] . "</td>"
    . "</tr>";
    $sum=$sum+$row1['preis'];
       }
    } 
    echo "Summ  = ".$sum; }



echo "</table>"
. "</div>";
```

Comment: Sorry but this don't work for me. I get this now: davidSumm = 0martinSumm = 0
ID Abholdatum Fahrer Preis

Answer (score 0):

I tested this, It should work:

```
$new = 1;
$sum = 0;
$last_fahrer = 'initial';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
   if($last_fahrer != $row['fahrer'] && $last_fahrer != 'initial') {
      echo "<tr>"
        . '<td colspan="3">Summ</td>'
        . "<td>" . $sum . "</td>"
        . "</tr>";
      $sum = 0;
      $new = 1;
   }
   if($new == 1) {
      echo "<tr>"
      . '<td colspan="4">' . ucwords($row["fahrer"])
      . '</td>'
      . '</tr>';
      $new = 0;
   }
      echo "<tr>"
      . "<td>" . $row['id'] ."</td>"
      . "<td>" . $row['abholdatum'] ."</td>"
      . "<td>" .  $row['fahrer'] . "</td>"
      . "<td>" . $row['preis'] . "</td>"
      . "</tr>";
      $last_fahrer = $row['fahrer'];
      $sum = $sum + $row['preis'];
}

echo "<tr>"
. '<td colspan="3">Summ</td>'
. "<td>" . $sum . "</td>"
. "</tr>"
. "</table>"
  . "</div>";
```

Comment: I get nothing :) just white screen.

Comment: Try it now, I made a few updates that should make it work exactly.